# How can I replace all chars in string except another string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

Given a string and a non-empty word string, return a version of the original String where all chars have been replaced by pluses ("+"), except for appearances of the word string which are preserved unchanged. 
http://codingbat.com/prob/p170829

How can I resolve  this task  with next code

```
String s=str.replaceAll("[^("+ word +")]", "+");
```

How can I replace all chars except exactly chars from word, because compilation with this code has two failed tests.

Comment: You asked same question earlier. Stop asking same question.

Comment: No, it's not the same. I got another problem now

Comment: You really need to adapt your english. I don't even understand what you are trying to say...

Comment: @redavlr Then you could at least have come up with a new title for the question...go back and edit your original question. It's two hours old and has no accepted answer yet.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is probably to use String.replaceAll():

```
String out = str.replaceAll("[^word]", "+");
```

This should replace all the letters except the string 'word'

Comment: `"drow"` should be `"++++"`, however it becomes `"drow"`.

Comment: You are excluding the *character class* consisting of the letters `w`, `o`, `r`, and `d`. This is elementary regex stuff.